# Session table growing after switch to redis

Tags: mysql, session, redis, enterprise-1.13

We recently switched our sessions to REDIS and we noticed that our session table in the database is growing and is now 15gb

Here is my config

```
 <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
             <redis_session>
                <host>xxxxx</host>
                <port>6379</port>
                <password>xxxxxxxxxx</password>
                <timeout>2.5</timeout>  
                <persistent></persistent>  
                <db>0</db>
                <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>
                <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> 
                <log_level>4</log_level>
                <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>
                <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>  
                <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
                <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime> 
              </redis_session>
```

Comment: Are there any sessions stored in the redis DB at all? Or in the MySQL DB only?

Comment: And I assume you use Cm_RedisSession. I think that module is deactivated by default. And you can try running the migrateSessions_mysql_redis.php script to move the sessions from mysql to redis. Wonder if that script works or fails when you run it.

Comment: Yes we are getting sessions stored in REDIS and I completely truncated the session table before I migrated. (Maybe that is what I did wrong?)

Comment: Hm, interesting. I think I would run the migration script and check if the MySQL DB gets filled again. Did you flush the config cache?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl Would I have to run the migration script on a new install?

Comment: I never migrated from MySQL to redis but given the contents from the php file I don't think that a new install is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the module Cm_RedisSession.xml was set to false and that this needs to true. I had thought that with the new version of Magento we would use the Mage_ name space and the Cm_ name space was legacy.

Comment: Happy you solved it

Comment: hm, very strange after you said - `Yes we are getting sessions stored in REDIS `  how is that even possible if redis extension was `false`? so i think your cache is going to `<db>0</db>` as well?? :)